# So, as I was offering the prayer of Isha and I accidentally prayed 4 sunnahs, 4 farz, but instead of 2 sunnah, I offered 4. Is this permissible?

Tags: salat

However, unsure, I reoffered the 2 sunnah. Thank you for answering. I would especially love an 'in depth' answer! JazakAllah!

Answer (score 1):

Sunnahs are essentialy Nafls (just more emphasised / preferred), and Nafls are read in pairs of rakhaats. So my understanding is that in your case, provided you did this unintentionally, the first two rakhaats count as your Sunnah and the last two count as Nafl. If this happens again, make sure not to stop after three, as that makes the whole salah invalid (based on what I said above that Nafls are read in pairs).